# Sequence Diagram: Extra White space at the top, "Shape protection, container, and/or layer properties prevent complete execution of this command."

Tags: microsoft-visio, uml

I'm using Visio 2010.  I finished my sequence diagram.  When I copy everything to paste into MS Word, I get a lot of white space at the top.  All the shapes are inside of a blue box that gets copied over.  If I try to drag those lines in in Visio, I get the message "Shape protection, container, and/or layer properties prevent complete execution of this command."  I did select all shapes and removed all shape protections, and I still get this message.  I don't see any layers